# Why has my camera stopped taking pictures in low light?

Tags: exposure, shutter-speed, low-light

I have had a Canon T1i for about 4 years now and I've noticed that it won't take pictures in low light even when I'm in manual mode. I've taken some pictures using time exposure in "bulb" and even then sometimes it won't release the shutter. Any ideas why?

Comment: How dark do you mean by "low light"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't I take a photo in dark with auto focus, manual mode?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/14448/why-cant-i-take-a-photo-in-dark-with-auto-focus-manual-mode)

Comment: are you using autofocus?

Answer (score 1):

The manual (M) mode only means the light metering is manual. Focusing is still automatic unless you toggle the MF/AF switch on the lens. In your case, there's simply too little light available for the AF system to find focus, and by default the camera will refuse to take a picture in this situation.

[How to Force my Nikon D5000 to take a photo in low light?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8263/how-to-force-my-nikon-d5000-to-take-a-photo-in-low-light)

[Why can't I take a photo in dark with auto focus, manual mode?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/14448/why-cant-i-take-a-photo-in-dark-with-auto-focus-manual-mode)

Comment: When a question is a clear duplicate of an existing one, please flag as such rather than answering. It's far more helpful to future visitors to have a canonical (no pun intended) question with all the answers in one place.

Comment: Actually this was a good answer for me. I believe there may be differences in the workings of the Canon and Nikon. I like your sense of humor by the way.

Comment: @Rick I didn't say it wasn't a good answer — it's a fine answer. This isn't a complaint, really, it's just what is better for building a good long-term store of knowledge here.